# Total number of cells on each MGRS grid level

Tags: geocoding, algorithm, grids-graticules, mgrs

I'm trying to figure out how [MGRS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_Grid_Reference_System) grid looks like in a whole. I've already read wiki page and some articles but still didn't find the answer to my question.

As I understand:

1. level (`100 × 100` km cells) - 60 columns × 20 rows = `1,200` cells
2. level (`10 × 10` km cells) - 10 columns × 10 rows = 100 cells (1200 * 100 = `120,000` total)
3. level (`1 × 1` km cells) - 10 columns × 10 rows = 100 cells (1200 * 100 * 100 = `12,000,000` total)
4. level (`100 × 100` m cells) - 10 columns × 10 rows = 100 cells (1200 * 100 * 100 * 100 = `1,200,000,000` total)
5. ...

Is it right or did I misunderstood something?

Comment: It's a little more complicated than that, because the poles have less area than the equator, so while there's *addressing* for the cells, they may not be present.